# How to execute event on dynamic generated text box in c# imminently when text box created

Tags: c#, .net, list

I created Dynamic Text Box using List in C# and i want to execute event immediately after text box is created

Following is my code.

```
    private List<TextBox> txtTotalCost = new List<TextBox>();

    private void btnMaterialAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbTotalCost = new TextBox();
        tbTotalCost.Location = new Point(652, RowCount * 22);
        tbTotalCost.Width = 60;
        txtTotalCost.Add(tbTotalCost);
        tbTotalCost.MouseClick += tbTotalCost_TextChanged;
        panel1.Controls.Add(tbTotalCost);
     }

    void tbTotalCost_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)       
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        TotalCost = CanadianCost * Qut;
        tb.Text = TotalCost.ToString();
        return;
    }
```

I want to generate or execute event as text box created i do now want to mouse click or text_change.
And want to display multiplication of two integer inside

how can i do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
private void btnMaterialAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbTotalCost = new TextBox();
    tbTotalCost.Location = new Point(652, RowCount * 22);
    tbTotalCost.Width = 60;
    txtTotalCost.Add(tbTotalCost);
    tbTotalCost.MouseClick += tbTotalCost_TextChanged;
    panel1.Controls.Add(tbTotalCost);
    tbTotalCost_TextChanged(tbTotalCost, null);  // <-- this line.
 }
```

Comment: Microsoft recommends passing `EventArgs.Empty` instead of `null` when calling an event handler that doesn't use EventArgs.  Technically it won't hurt anything to pass `null` in this case, but `EventArgs.Empty` is a good habit to get in to.

Comment: IT will Just Add 0 Value default to Dynamic Created Text box but still you have to click on Text box to Trigger event.

Comment: This method /should/ work just fine.  It's hard to tell why it isn't working in your case without seeing more of your code and having a clearer idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is works fine, but i want to display multiplication of previously  dynamic created text box, immediately to this new text box when it is  created. i do not want to click on text box or change text of new text box to trigger event.

Comment: You will need to keep track of the previously created textbox, in that case.